# Angular2 - What to do when event emitter is not the event target?

Tags: angular, events, html-table, row

I want to get the row element of a table on a mouseover event. The problem is that the event target is the td element under the cursor not the row element itself. That has nothing to do with angular so far. It's a DOM thing.
Here is my component:

```
@Component({
 //....
 template: `
  <tr *ngFor="#row of rows;" (mouseover)="onRowHover($event)">
   <td *ngFor="#cell of row.cells">{{cell.value}}</td>
  </tr>`
 })
 export class Table {
  private onRowHover(event) {
   console.log("hover", event.target); //will print "hover <td>"
  }
 }
```

To solve this, i usually get the row by using 'this', which would be the row element:

```
<tr onmouseover="console.log("hover", this)"> <!-- Will print "hover <row>" -->
```

So the question is: How do i access the 'this' or the row element in Angular2? Is there something like:

```
<tr ... (mouseover)="onRowHover($event, $this)" >
```

My workaround for now is to get the parent of the event.target which is the appropriate tr-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
 <tr #tr *ngFor="#row of rows;" (mouseover)="onRowHover(tr)"></tr>
```

Comment: That gives me the row data context but not the tr DOM Element

Comment: <tr *ngFor="#row of rows;" (mouseover)="onRowHover($event)"></tr> 
and then use $event.target

Comment: Please read the question. The problem is, that the event target is not the row but the td element

Comment: sorry,
i think we have 2 options:
1) <tr #tr *ngFor="#row of rows;" (mouseover)="onRowHover(tr)"></tr>
2) <tr *ngFor="#row of rows;" (mouseover)="onRowHover($event)"></tr> with $event.target.parentNode

Comment: Yes, that did it. The second option was my workaround. Thanks a lot. Could you please edit your answer that i can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the #tr solution. The second option was already my workaround as pointed out in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(event.path[0]);
```

returns the the inner-most element the mouse is over

Comment: event.path is undefined

Comment: I tried it in a plunker but I dropped it because it was so simple anyway.

Comment: I don't know which Browser you are using. But this doesn't work on Firefox. Tried it on chrome, though, where it worked.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried with Firefox but googled and saw an old bug fixed long ago and assumed it would work there as well. In this case @kit s answer is probably the better bet.

Comment: `event.target` returns the `td` for me on Firefox and Chrome.